Name this modification of Newton's method
To reduce the cost of the Newton-Raphson method for multivariate rootfinding, a common trick is keeping the Jacobian matrix fixed for several iterations. For instance, in pseudocode:
Input: x0 in R^n, functions f, J; number of steps between each update m
Output: an approximate solution x to the equation f(x) = 0.

x = x0
for k = 0, 1, 2, ... :
  if k is a multiple of m:
    A = J(x)
    compute a matrix factorization of A (e.g., LU)
    # else the last computed A is reused
  end
  x = x - A \ f(x)  # using the computed factorization
end

This method seems to be commonly known and used, but does it have a name?

I remember it is called quasi newton method, but I'm not 100% sure and don't have a reference at hand.

It's often called a modified Newton method.

Thanks, but please do not use comments to answer questions here. :)

"Folklore" suggests that it doesn't have a theoretical basis. As others have pointed out, that's not true. It's also widely used -- every nonlinear solver package uses this approach because, typically, computing the Jacobian matrix is expensive.

@WolfgangBangerth I see your point; I have replaced that word.

It's the lagged Newton method. You can find more details in this paper for example:
"LOW-RANK QUASI-NEWTON UPDATES FOR ROBUST JACOBIAN LAGGING IN NEWTON METHODS"
In the original paper: "A Modification of Newton's Method" it is not given a name, it's just called a modification of Newton. Moreover in the above paper a finite difference approximation of the Jacobian is considered.

Probably worth noting that time-lagging or time-delay (regularization) does not apply only to Newton. See for example: "Time-delay regularization of anisotropic diffusion and image processing". Time-lagging is also sometimes used to refer to the fixed-point iteration/Kacanov method employed for quasi-linear PDEs (see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.10137):
$$-\operatorname{div}(g(|\nabla u|^2)\nabla u) = f \to -\operatorname{div}(g(|\nabla u^k|^2)\nabla u^{k+1}) = f \to D^TG(u^k)Du^{k+1} = f.$$
The latter can be related to Newton however. Suppose you have:
$$A(x)x = b \to A(x^k)x^{k+1} = b \to x^{k+1} = (A(x^k))^{-1}b.$$
In the above $F(x) = A(x)x-b$. Differentiating w.r.t. $x$ yields $J_F(x) = A(x) + A'(x)x$. And the Newton iteration:
$$x^{k+1} = x^k - (J_F(x^k))^{-1}F(x^k) = x^k - (A(x^k) + A'(x^k)x^k)^{-1}(A(x^k)x^k-b).$$
So you can see that the Kacanov iteration is really Newton with the term $A'(x)x$ dropped (provided $A(x^k)$ is invertible).

Reusing Jacobians/Jacobian factorization in successive time steps is also somewhat common in implicit integrators for problems small enough that you don't need a Krylov method

Thanks! The name Newton-Shamanskii, from the original paper that you cite, also seems common (and now I also recall seeing it in the past).
